# How to set LineRenderer to single color when selecting AnimationType: None?

Tags: unity, c#

The problem is when i'm trying to use the None mode the method IEnumerator SelectAnimation should get only type of IEnumerator and I'm not sure how to use the None mode?

When starting with the None mode or changing to the None mode at runtime i want it to set the linerenderer default original color or any selected single color(like selected Color.Red).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class LineRendererColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimationType { None, SingleColorMorph, MultiColorMorph, Shuffle, Shift };
    LineRenderer myLineRenderer;
    Coroutine _animationInProgress;
    public float morphTime;

    [SerializeField]
    AnimationType _animationType;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    AnimationType _cachedAnimationType;
    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (_animationType != _cachedAnimationType)
        {
            if (_animationInProgress == null)
                _cachedAnimationType = _animationType;
            else
                StartAnimation(_animationType);
        }
    }
#endif

    void StartAnimation(AnimationType animType)
    {
        _animationType = animType;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        _cachedAnimationType = animType;
#endif

        if (_animationInProgress != null)
            StopCoroutine(_animationInProgress);

        _animationInProgress = StartCoroutine(SelectAnimation(animType));
    }

    IEnumerator SelectAnimation(AnimationType animType)
    {
        switch (animType)
        {
            case AnimationType.SingleColorMorph:
                return RandomSingleColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime);
            case AnimationType.MultiColorMorph:
                return RandomMultiColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime);
            case AnimationType.Shuffle:
                return ShuffleGradient(myLineRenderer, .5f);
            case AnimationType.Shift:
                return AnimateLoop(myLineRenderer);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        myLineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        StartAnimation(_animationType);
    }

    void SetSingleColor(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.startColor = newColor;
        lineRendererToChange.endColor = newColor;
    }

    void SetSingleColor2(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = new Gradient();

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];
        tempColorKeys[0] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 0);
        tempColorKeys[1] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 1);

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    void SetSingleColor3(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = tempGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            tempColorKeys[i].color = newColor;
        }

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    IEnumerator ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, float waitTime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ShuffleGradient(targetLineRenderer);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

    void ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Color tempColor = newColorKeys[i].color;
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, newColorKeys.Length - 1);
            newColorKeys[i].color = newColorKeys[randomIndex].color;
            newColorKeys[randomIndex].color = tempColor;
        }
        Gradient tempGradient = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient;
        tempGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys;
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }


    IEnumerator RandomMultiColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys;
            GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = GenerateRandomColorKeys(initialColorKeys);
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                GradientColorKey[] currentColorKeys = GradientColorKeyLerp(initialColorKeys, newColorKeys, progress);
                Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
                tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys;
                lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    GradientColorKey[] GradientColorKeyLerp(GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys, GradientColorKey[] endColorKeys, float progress)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[initialColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = Color.Lerp(initialColorKeys[i].color, endColorKeys[i].color, progress);
            newColorKeys[i].time = initialColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //assigns new color to each colorkey and uses Time from incomingColorKeys
    GradientColorKey[] GenerateRandomColorKeys(GradientColorKey[] incomingColorKeys)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[incomingColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = RandomColor();
            newColorKeys[i].time = incomingColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //asumes Single color, 2 colorkeys
    IEnumerator RandomSingleColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;
        Color initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
        //this reduces colorkey amount to 2 just in case.
        SetSingleColor2(lineRendererToChange, initialColor);

        while (true)
        {
            initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
            Color targetColor = RandomColor();
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                Color currentColor = Color.Lerp(initialColor, targetColor, progress);
                SetSingleColor(lineRendererToChange, currentColor);
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //Basically Color.Lerp?
    Color ColorLerpMath(Color firstColor, Color secondColor, float progress)
    {
        Vector3 firstRGB = new Vector3(firstColor.r, firstColor.g, firstColor.b);
        Vector3 secondRGB = new Vector3(secondColor.r, secondColor.g, secondColor.b);
        Vector3 difference = secondRGB - firstRGB;
        Vector3 lerpedRGB = firstRGB + (progress * difference);
        return new Color(lerpedRGB.x, lerpedRGB.y, lerpedRGB.z);
    }

    Color RandomColor()
    {
        return new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
    }

    //returns the gradient with a copy of the first key for intersection purposes.
    Gradient AddInitialCopy(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> newColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        Color interSectionColor = newColorKeys[0].color;
        newColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(interSectionColor, 0));
        Gradient newInitGradient = new Gradient();
        newInitGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys.ToArray();
        return newInitGradient;
    }

    //remove first and last keys since they dont shift.
    List<GradientColorKey> RemoveFirstAndLast(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(currentColorKeys.Count - 1);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentColorKeys;
    }

    Color GetIntersectionColor(List<GradientColorKey> incomingKeys, int lowestIndex, int highestIndex)
    {
        Color firstColor = incomingKeys[lowestIndex].color;
        Color lastColor = incomingKeys[highestIndex].color;
        float distance = 1 - (incomingKeys[highestIndex].time - incomingKeys[lowestIndex].time);
        float colorLerpAmount = (1f - incomingKeys[highestIndex].time) / distance; ;
        Color newIntersectionColor = Color.Lerp(lastColor, firstColor, colorLerpAmount);
        return newIntersectionColor;
    }

    //accepts max 7 colors, 1st and last should be at 0 and 1
    IEnumerator AnimateLoop(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float movementPerTick = .001f)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = AddInitialCopy(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);

        while (true)
        {
            List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = RemoveFirstAndLast(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);
            float highestTime = 0;
            float lowestTime = 1;
            int highestIndex = currentColorKeys.Count - 1;
            int lowestIndex = 0;
            //Move all inner ones.
            for (int i = 0; i < currentColorKeys.Count; i++)
            {
                GradientColorKey tempColorKey = currentColorKeys[i];
                float newTime = tempColorKey.time + movementPerTick;

                if (newTime > 1)
                {
                    newTime = newTime - 1;
                }
                tempColorKey.time = newTime;
                currentColorKeys[i] = tempColorKey;
                if (newTime < lowestTime)
                {
                    lowestTime = newTime;
                    lowestIndex = i;
                }
                if (newTime > highestTime)
                {
                    highestTime = newTime;
                    highestIndex = i;
                }
            }
            Color newIntersectionColor = GetIntersectionColor(currentColorKeys, lowestIndex, highestIndex);
            currentColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 0));
            currentColorKeys.Add(new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 1));
            Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
            tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys.ToArray();
            lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void AssignGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, Gradient newGradient)
    {
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = newGradient;
    }

    void DrawTestLine()
    {
        Vector3 firstPos = new Vector3(-5, 0, 0);
        Vector3 secondPos = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        int resolution = 100;
        myLineRenderer.positionCount = resolution;
        myLineRenderer.SetPositions(MakeLine(firstPos, secondPos, 100));
    }

    //makes a line from point A to point B with resolution of size points
    Vector3[] MakeLine(Vector3 initPos, Vector3 endPos, int points)
    {
        Vector3 difference = endPos - initPos;
        Vector3[] newLine = new Vector3[points];
        Vector3 differencePerPoint = difference / (float)(points - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            newLine[i] = initPos + (differencePerPoint * i);
        }
        return newLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either add is as a default, you do not have one `default: return null;` or add in the switch method a `None` branch and define what should happen

Comment: "the linerenderer default original color **or** any selected single color" well, which is it? The original colour, or a selected colour? It can't be both, so you need to pick one, or define the rule that the code should use to pick. If you want it to use a selected colour, then you need to specify where that colour gets selected.

Comment: Working, thanks.